# Binary matrices such with distinct columns such that after the removal of any one row the columns are no longer distinct

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, binary

Let $A$ be an $m \times 2^n$ binary (i.e. with entries from $\{0,1\}$) matrix where $m \gg n$, such that all columns of $A$ are distinct $m$-bit bitwords. Suppose further that by removing any row of $A$ we obtain a $(m-1)\times 2^n$ matrix whose columns are no longer unique in the above sense.

For any such matrix one clearly has the upper bound $m < 2^{n}$. What is the best possible upper bound on $m$ in terms of $n$?

Example for $n = 3, m = 5$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

---

Edit: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956879/deleting-a-line-of-a-in-mathcalm-n-mathbbz-2-mathbbz-to-get-again-a?rq=1) is a very closely related question.

Comment: It seems impossible to have such a matrix

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @VezenBU I'm sorry I think you are right. I rewrote the question and added an example as well. Hopefully, this question makes more sense now.

Comment: Over what ring / field?

Comment: Does that matter? Why? @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: @gen Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=[c_1,...,c_n]$ where $c_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $A$, Let  $E_k = \{(i,j): c_i + c_j = e_k \}$. So we have $|E_k| \geq 1$, $\forall k$ since removing $k^{th}$ row will make some two columns same. Further $i$ appears only once in $E_k$, since otherwise $c_i + c_j + c_i + c_l = e_k + e_k$ which implies $c_j = c_l$ contradicting distinctness of columns.  If there is a column index $i$ which is not present in any tuple in any set $E_k$ then we can remove that column and tighten the upper bound. Clearly rank$(A) = m$, since we can linearly combine the columns and generate $\{e_1,...,e_{m}\}$. Hence $m > 2^n$ is impossible since $rank(A) = m \leq 2^n$. $m = 2^n-1$ can be attained by matrix, $A=[0,e_1,...,e_m]$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. As for your example, I'm not sure I follow why that would qualify. Take $n=2$ and consider the example $A$ you gave. Isn't the 4th row of this square matrix all zeros? How can this row discriminate two distinct columns that become identical after erasing this row?

Comment: Hi... there are only 3 rows in my matrix A. ie m=2^n-1 =3 for n=2. Check ur bound because the construction of A i gave beats the bound given in question.

Comment: The matrix A I gave has m+1 columns with first column all 0s and second column e_1 and third column e_2 .... last column e_m

Comment: The example A I gave and the upper bound solves the problem except m=2^n .

Comment: I see, I think you are right, and my earlier bound was wrong. Can you edit your answer a little bit so I can undo my downvote?

Comment: Edited...glad we agreed